# How to get high quality audio to text with the confidence the text will be as accurate as possible

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

So I am starting to do research for a project, and I already found way too many tools to use, without knowing their pros and cons. I would love to either where could I get a professional opinion on the matter (I'm not going to outdo someone with years of experience by simply doing a few weeks of research), or get some opinion of what qualities and properties a program should have to be considered.

My project consists of .wav files, recorded in a professional studio set up to get as much quality and as few interferences as possible, and I would like a reliable tool to put that in text (meaning, I give it the file, it returns some kind of text file). Ideally this would be done so later on I can automate the task.

The language is going to be Spanish (maybe that gives some trouble?), and the idea is to analyze the outputs, frequenzy, relationship between different recordings and so on, that's why I am worried about accuracy.

Comment: The way to get most accuracy is to hire a human transcriber. For software solutions there is a separate SO site for software recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you for the tip!! Didn't know about it